# compare elements in list with nested loops

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I am looking for a variant to determine if a character ("b") in a list of strings follows a certain character ("a") using nested loops. The program should then count the total number of strings for which the above is true.

I have written the following code that works for me using .find

```
nStrings = int ( input ( "input n amount of strings: " ))

listStr = [ ]

sumStr = 0

for i in range (0, len(nStrings)):

    newStr = input ("enter string: ")

    listn.append(newStr)

for i in range (0, len(listStr)):

    if listn[i].find("a") < listn[i].find("b"):

        sumStr = sumStr + 1

print("sumStr")
```

However, I am searching for a way to do this with nested loops.

My approach currently is

```
for i in range (0, len(listStr)):

    if listStr[i] == "a":

        foundA = i

        for j in range (i+1, len(listStr)):

              if list[j] == "b":

                   foundB = j

              if foundA < foundB:

                  afterA = True
```

This, however, does not work at all for me. If tried a few variants, but I am sure I am making a logical error.

Comment: You should reduce your problem to “check for a single string, whether one character appears before another character”. Then, when you have done that, you apply this solution to a list of strings. You already did this kind-of in your first solution, but in your second you are mixing up things: You are iterating over the list of strings, expecting individual members of that list to be characters.

Comment: Why would you want to use nested loops for this problem? Do you want to avoid `str.find()`?

Comment: @Jasper, correct, seeking a way to replace find in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the function to check whether `b` occurs after `a` in a String:

```
def a_before_b(haystack):
  found_a = False
  for letter in haystack:
    if letter == 'a':
      found_a = True
    elif letter == 'b' and found_a:    # we found 'b' and already have found 'a' earlier
      return True

  return False
```

To avoid `.find()`, use this method instead of the line

```
    if listn[i].find("a") < listn[i].find("b"):
```

in your code, like this:

```
   if a_before_b(listn[i]):
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use nested `for` loops for this comparison, instead you can use the `str.find()` method (which, as @cricket_007 points out, is an implied loop):

```
def getinput():
  nStrings = int(input("inuput n amount of strings:"))
  l = []
  for i in range(nStrings):
    l.append(input('enter string\n'))
  return l
def compare(itm): 
  if 'a' in itm and 'b' in itm:
    return True if itm.find('a') < itm.find('b') else False
  else:
    return None

listStr = getinput() 
print zip(listStr, map(compare, listStr))
```

given inputs of: `['David', 'alphabet', 'bagpipes']`, this should return the tuples in a list:

```
[('David', None), ('alphabet', True), ('bagpipes', False)]
```

Comment: That's the same thing, it just returns -1 instead of an error if the substring isn't found.

Comment: @cricket_007 if you have a revision to make that would improve this, feel free to make the revision. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking me to do...

Comment: What I mean is "not using two explicit `for` loops"... @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

You can use one loop

```
letter1 = "a" 
letter2 = "b" 
for i in range (0, len(listStr)):
    if listStr[i] == letter1:
        pos1 = i
    if listStr[i] == letter2:
        pos2 = i

foundAfter = (pos2 > pos1) # an error is here if the letters weren't found at all
```

Comment: @DavidZemens - he's only correcting your semantics. You are both right lol :)

Comment: @cricket_007, if a string[i] contains more than one character, the condition == letter1 would not return a value, i.e. "abc" != "a"

Comment: @ThomasFuchs - I assumed `listStr` was a string. It doesn't make sense for string[i] to contain more than one letter because that means the character at position i of the string